# Why atom with unpaired electrons is paramagnetic?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-moment

I know when electron spins are exposed to a magnetic field, they align so that their moments are parallel to the field. But why is there no paramagneticity for paired electrons?

The book says it's because spins in opposite directions are paired, but I can't understand.
Is it impossible to tilt the spin axis of a paired electron?

Comment: _Is it impossible to tilt the spin axis of a paired electron?_ Classical thinking in quantum systems will lead to misunderstandings. The fact is that two electrons in an orbital have opposite spins and so cancel each other’s magnetic fields.

Comment: @josephh Do you mean that magnetic field due to one spin  can be cancelled by other spin?

Comment: There is no _net_ magnetic field/moment. An important point is to not think that the motion of an electron “around” an atom is what creates a magnetic field (as is the case for classical charged particles in motion). The take away is that substances with paired electrons have a zero moment and are therefore diamagnetic. Avoid thinking classically as this is a common mistake that causes confusion.